# Create multiple related objects in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using `Django 2.0`

I have two models

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class META:
        verbose_name_plural = 'chapters'
        db_table = 'chapters'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ChapterQuestion(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class META:
        verbose_name_plural = 'chapter questions'
        db_table = 'chapter_questions'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

Since Each `ChapterQuestion` belongs to only one `Chapter`, I think it could be `Many-to-one` relation.

My **admin.py** contain only

```
admin.site.register(Chapter)
admin.site.register(ChapterQuestion)
```

**I want to be able to add/edit multiple questions while creating/editing chapter using `Django Admin`.**

But Django Admin is showing only `chapter` fields

[image]

**Also, I want `created_by` column to be field automatically by logged in user and remove from form.**

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question 5 years ago. It saved me from creating a view just for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use inline forms

```
class ChapterQuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ChapterQuestion

@admin.register(Chapter)
class ChapterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["course","name","created_by"]
    inlines = [ChapterQuestionInline]
```